# sort command on vi: E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version

Tags: sorting, vi, linux-mint, uniq

I was trying to sort lines in [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi). When I used the command `:sort`, I get

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version
```

I work on [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) and I already updated everything.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :!sort to use the external Unix command line sort.